# Jquery scroll to a div after click a button then hide the button after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to hide a button when window scroll to a div and show again when scroll out from this div. I also wanted after click on this button this window will scroll to the div and hide the div. But problem is after click on the button and scroll to the div the button not hiddeing. here is my code

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        
        var scroll_top = $("#right-side-bar").offset().top;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < scroll_top ) {
            $(".timestsw-apply-stic").addClass('apply-sticky-btn');
        } else {
            $(".timestsw-apply-stic").removeClass('apply-sticky-btn');
        }
    });
    $('a#stick').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#right-side-bar").offset().top
        }, 500,function () {
        
            $(".timestsw-apply-stic").removeClass('apply-sticky-btn');
        });


    })
  });
```

please help me how can i solve this. thanks